# WSO2 Identity Server - LDAP working in read-only mode but is set to false

Tags: exception, ldap, wso2, claims, wso2-identity-server

`<Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>` - this is set in usr-mgt.xml in my identity server.

When I try to invoke the method for setting user claim value - storeManager.setUserClaimValue(String userName, String claimURI, String claimValue,String profileName) it gives me this exception:

`org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.`

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is the UserStoreManager you are using ?

Comment: This is the code I use:

UserRealm realm = WSRealmBuilder.createWSRealm(Constants.SERVER_URL,
    cookie, Constants.CONFIG_CONTEXT);

UserStoreManager storeManager = realm.getUserStoreManager();

I get the cookie string after AuthenticationAdminStub.login()

Answer (score 0):

If the LDAP on User Store manager class is to be ReadWrite please call the below class on the  user-mgt.xml within the

class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager"

If the LDAP on User Store manager class is to be Read only please call the below class on the  user-mgt.xml  within the

class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager

Comment: Yes, you have to use the ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager if you want to do write operations.